# On R: i can't execute build function with a list(), input

Tags: r

I'm new to R and trying to calculate using my own function:

```
library(lubridate)
diffWeekdays<-function(df,ds){
  df<-as.Date(df)
  ds<-as.Date(ds)

    ndays<-as.integer(0)
  for(i in ds:df) {
    if(wday(ds)>1& wday(ds)<7){ #only weekdays count
      ndays<-ndays+1
    }
   ds<-ds+1
  }
    if(ndays>0){
      ndays<-ndays-1
    }
  return(ndays)
}
```

I have a B (list[2]). When I do B[2] or B[1], all the values are showed, but when i do

```
diffWeekdays(B[[2]],B[[1]])
```

I get the error:
Error in as.Date.default(df) :
do not know how to convert 'df' to class "Date"

```
>B[[2]]
```

6193 2012-07-19
6194 2012-07-17
6195 2012-07-16

Could someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: `str` might help you identify types of things. So perhaps add `print(str(df))` and similar inside your function for debugging.

Comment: Reading the help on extraction (`help("Extract")`) might help explain the difference between `[` and `[[`.